# Please explain this statement: Let $D$ be an interval (finite or infinite) on the real line $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> Let $D$ be an interval (finite or infinite) on the real line $\mathbb{R}$.

Please explain: how can we have both infinite and finite intervals?
If intervals are defined by number of points, then isn't any "interval" on the real line trivially infinite?
If intervals are defined by their length, then isn't any "interval" on the real line trivially finite?

Comment: It seems that here sets like $(a,\infty)$, $(-\infty,a)$ and $(-\infty,\infty)$ are also accepted as intervals.

Comment: I see. I hadn't considered that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When one refers to a finite/infinite interval, it refers to the length of the interval.

An interval can be finite. For example:
$$(0,1) = \{x\in\mathbb{R}\ : \ 0<x<1\} \text{ has length $1$}.$$

But it can also be infinite. For example:
$$(0,\infty) = \{x\in\mathbb{R}\ : \ 0<x<\infty\} \text{ has length $\infty$}.$$

In general, an interval has an infinite number of points. Only the case where both limits of a closed interval coincide gives an interval with a finite number of points. For example, $[1,1]=\{1\}$ has just one point.

Answer (score 1):

One way to define an interval is that it is a subset $I$ such that whenever $x,y \in I$ and $x<z<y$, we can conclude that $z \in I$. (This has the benefit of being generalisable to more complex ordered sets)

In this sense, $(a, \infty)$, $(- \infty,a)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are all intervals.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a "finite" intervall is a bounded intervall, an an "infinite" intervall is an intervall, which is not bounded.